# Specific symmetric or skew-symmetric matrix for real bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

For a real bilinear form $Q:V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$. $V$ is of dimension $2n$, for a basis $\{...,v_i,...\}$, we define a matrix $[Q_{ij}]$ with $Q_{ij}=Q(v_i,v_j)$.

How to see that if $Q$ is skew-symmetric, then there exists a basis, $\{...,v_i,...\}$, s.t.

$ [Q_{ij}]= 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
0&I_g\\-I_g&0 
\end{matrix}
\bigg]
$

and if $Q$ is symmetric, then there exists a basis, $\{...,v_i,...\}$, s.t.
$[Q_{ij}]=$

$ [Q_{ij}]= 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
I_h&0\\0&-I_k 
\end{matrix}
\bigg]
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Q$ is skew-symmetric. Pick a nonzero $v \in V$, and assuming $Q$ is nondegenerate, then there is some $w \in V$ so that $Q(v,w) = \lambda \neq 0$. Rescale $w \mapsto \frac{1}{\lambda}w$ so that $Q(v,w)=1$. Rename the vectors $v=x_1$ and $w = y_1$. Now look at the subspace $\mathrm{Span}(x_1,y_1)^\perp$ (where $\perp$ is with repsect to $Q$), which is of dimension $2n-2 = 2(n-1)$ and repeat, to build a basis $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n$. Then the matrix of $Q$ in this basis is by construction
$$ Q = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & \mathrm{Id}_n \\ -\mathrm{Id}_n & 0 \end{array}\right) $$

The idea is similar for the symmetric case. Start with nonzero $v$ for which $Q(v,v) \neq 0$ and rescale $v$ so that $Q(v,v) = \pm 1$. Now look at $v^\perp$, which is of dimension one less, and repeat to build a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ where $Q(v_i,v_i) = \pm 1$.

Comment: but where did we use skew-symmetric?

Comment: Oops, the bottom corner of the matrix should be negative. Typo on my part. Fixing it now.

Comment: Again where did you use skew-symmetric for the construction?

Comment: The skew-symmetric assumption is why the bottom left corner of the matrix is $-\mathrm{Id}_n$, and why we only needed to consider $Q(v,w)$ and not also $Q(w,v)$.